# Python: importing a module with parameters?

Tags: python, logging, parameters, import, module

I have a small logging wrapper module, `test.logging`:

```python
import logging

debuglog = "debug.log"
f = open(debuglog, 'w') # truncate the file
f.close()

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s: %(filename)s:%(lineno)d: %(message)s')

fh = logging.FileHandler(debuglog)
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)

def get(moduleName):
    return logging.getLogger("test." + moduleName)
```

and some modules that use it, such as `test.example`:

```python
import test.logging
logger = test.logging.get(__name__)

logger.info("This is an info message from test.example")
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to reduce the repetition of those first two lines that would appear in every submodule of `test`. I'd like to do something like:

```python
from test.logging get(__name__) as logger
logger.info("This is an info message from test.example")
```

Or even better, if I could also omit `__name__` and have `get()` automatically determine the module name. (From what I've gathered, this is possible with `inspect` module, but it can be incorrect if the caller is decorated or the program is compiled as an EXE.)

Is something like this possible?

Comment: What was wrong with importing it? You've just driven the `import` statement very crazy, mad and sad...

Comment: I'm just teaching myself Python and wondering if I can reduce the repetition. I try to avoid repetition whenever I can.

Comment: Wow. Have fun. Python is a great language. :)

Comment: It is a lot more fun than I thought it might be! Different from the Lua I'm used to, but very powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd stick with the code you have; less magic, more clarity.

You can access the module name of the calling code by accessing the frame from the stack, using [`sys._getframe()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe):

```
import sys

def get(moduleName=None):
    if moduleName is None:
        caller = sys._getframe(1)
        moduleName = caller.f_globals['__name__']
    return logging.getLogger("test." + moduleName)
```

making the module name optional:

```
from test import logging
logger = logging.get()
```

Yes, if your call to `logging.get()` was inside a decorator function you could in theory access a different set of globals (those of the module the decorator is defined in), but in the vast majority of cases that'd be exactly the module name you'd want to use. By making `moduleName` *optional* you retain the possibility to set it explicitly for corner cases.

Packaging a Python program to an executable (with `py2exe` or similar) can affect filenames (especially for the main script), but module names should remain the same.

Comment: "if your call to logging.get() was inside a *decorator* function" - not a *decorated* function? Maybe I misread...

Comment: @Rena you're not using decorators, so don't worry about that for the mean time. As you indulge deeper, you'll discover how to decorate your code. And trust, it makes it look incredibly pretty, hence the name decorators. :)

Comment: @Rena: usually it is a confusion about what context calls in the decorator wrapper are in. `sys._getframe(1)` will still return the frame of the *decorated* function if that is what you called from to `logging.get()`. A decorator is not going to make a difference there. If you need to go up *two* frames you could end up inspecting a decorator, but that doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to add to the already wonderful answer that there is:

In python, there is a dictionary holding every darn variables that you and the system have defined in the session. It's stored in `globals()`. If you type `globals()`, you'll get every variable and object that's been defined. For example:

```
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 
'__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>>
```

Whenever you access a variable, or an object (such as a file, or even a module itself), python looks for it in this dictionary. The import statement essentially gets the module and puts it into this dictionary. You can do a couple nifty things though. Instead of the boring `import this`, and `import that`, you can do:

```
import this.that
from this import that
```

This can help keep the session clean.